# Validar campos de diferentes longitudes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy en un dilema como evaluar un campo que puede contener números enteros de diferentes logitudes:

```
1234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

Es decir puede tener 10 , 37 o 49 dígitos enteros, actualmente lo realizo mediante un `select` donde selecciono el tipo de dígito a ingresar:

```
<select name="tipoFactura" id="tipoFactura" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled="">--------------</option>
  <option value="1">Preimpresa(10 digitos)</option>
  <option value="2">Electronica(37 digitos)</option>
  <option value="3">Electronica(49 digitos)</option>
</select>
```

con esto mediante **jQuery** agrego un `maxlength` al `input`:

```
$('#modalFactura #tipoFactura').on('change', function() {
  if(this.value == 1){
    $("#modalFactura #numero_autorizacion").attr({'minlength':'10','maxlength':'10'});
  }else if(this.value == 2){
    $("#modalFactura #numero_autorizacion").attr({'minlength':'37','maxlength':'37'});
  }else{
    $("#modalFactura #numero_autorizacion").attr({'minlength':'49','maxlength':'49'});
  }
});
```

Previamente para que solo admita números enteros uso expresiones regulares para que permita solo dígitos o números enteros.

```
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("numero_autorizacion"), function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

Comment: quieres validar que si elegiste primero 37 dígitos y los colocaste en el input y luego cambias de option a 10 dígitos, no te permita?

Comment: es decir deseo evaluar que el input puedar permitir ingresar sea 10, 37 ó 49 digitos no diferentes longitudes a estas..

Comment: Y qué problema estás teniendo con el código actual? Publicá el HTML. Si tus inputs tienen IDs, no uses 2 selectores desde jQuery, usá directamente el ID del input.

Comment: el problema es que es engorroso/molestoso para el usuario tener que estar seleccionando primero la longitud lo que me gustaria hacer es evaluarlo automaticamente sin el select..

Comment: Deberías agregar ese último comentario a la pregunta de otra forma no está claro que tipo de solución estás buscando y por ende o no está clara la pregunta o es principalmente basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no necesitas **JavaScript** para resolver lo que quieres, puedes resolverlo usando el atributo `pattern` de la siguiente manera:

Simplemente estamos condicionando el valor aceptado del input:

> Si los dígitos ingresados son números y su `length` es de 10 **O** Si los dígitos ingresados son números y su `length` es de 37 **O** Si los dígitos ingresados son números y su `length` es de 47 **entonces el valor es aceptado**.

Pero si los dígitos ingresados son diferentes a números y su `length` no está dentro de los ya estimados entonces la validación se ejecuta y arrojará el mensaje de error.

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{37}|[0-9]{49}" required title="Formato inválido">
  
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Buena solución. El input podría ser de tipo "number".

Comment: @azeós de hecho no se podría, el atributo pattern solo funciona con campos de texto, fecha, búsqueda, url, teléfono, correo electrónico y contraseña.... el campo número no está permitido para dicho atributo.

Comment: Gracias, no lo sabía. Busqué documentación pero no encontré.

Answer (score 0):

En este ejemplo:

Se está usando un eventListener llamado 'keyup' que detecta cada vez que presionas una tecla dentro del input asignado a la variable $numeroAutorizacion y se ejecuta el contenido de la función, así indicarías a tu cliente la cantidad de dígitos que debe ingresar:

```js
const validLengths = [10, 37, 49]
const $numeroAutorizacion = $('#numero_autorizacion')
const $longitudIndicador = $('#longitud-indicador')

$numeroAutorizacion.on('keyup', function() {
  let inputLength = this.value.length
  if (validLengths.find(i => i === inputLength)) {
    $numeroAutorizacion.css('outline-color', '')
  } else {
    $numeroAutorizacion.css('outline-color', 'red')
  }

  $longitudIndicador.html(inputLength)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="numero_autorizacion">
<span id="longitud-indicador"></span>
<p>debe tener una longitud de: 10, 37, 49</p>
```

Y para validar que no se envíe una cantidad de dígitos diferente a la que esperas, validarías que el formulario no se puede enviar reutilizando este funcionalidad:

```
// este fragmento de código debería estar dentro de una función que capture
// el evento submit del formulario y haga un preventDefault() de dicho
// evento que de cumplirse la condición entonces ejecute el evento y en caso
// de que no, avises a tu cliente que el input no tiene la longitud que esperas
if (validLengths.find(i => i === inputLength)) {
  // lógica para enviar el formulario.
} else {
  // algún tipo de alerta que describa que el formulario es inválido.
}
```

la variable validLengths contiene un array con las longitudes válidas para el formulario, entonces utilizando la función find() estás buscando para cada elemento de validLengths sea igual a tu inputLength(que es la longitud del value del input, ojo que deberás volver a pedir la actual longitud al intentar enviar el formulario y asignarla a una variable, digamos inputLength). Entonces de encontrar una coincidencia entre el elemento de validLengths que estás iterando con inputLength se ejecutará el if caso contrario el else.